# PHP - Form Div increment by 1 using for loop when button is click

Tags: php, mysql

I need to add a new form to store graph information everytime the button is clicked.

Everytime I click the button I should get the Div to increment by 1 so that the new information can be stored in the database with a unique id.

```
.jumbotron{
width:1000px;
height:100px;
background-color:lightblue;
}

<form action = "" method = "post">
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Add a new form">
</form>

<div class = "jumbotron">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
</div>
```

Refer here: https://jsfiddle.net/rk6eyym6/

Comment: And what is your problem, exactly?

Comment: I am unable to do a duplicate of the div by 1 using for loop when button is clicked.

Comment: Well, show us the code that gets executed on button submit.

Comment: Div increment to one? Or you meant ID? If ID is the case, you should manage your table structure and have a primary key and set it to `Auto Increment`. And what's up with those two inputs having the same `name` tags?

Comment: I have the javascript code not the PHP for loop.

Comment: Well, _show_ the javascript code.

Comment: Come on. Show it. We won't eat you.

Comment: I have edited my code. Apologies. I need the div to repeat after i click the button using php for loop.

Comment: Where is the difference? You get more divs. Since they are not stored somehow on the server side, why do you care _where_ they are duplicated? Why do you want to make things so much more complicated? That dos not help you with storing data later in the database. For that you only need to use post arrays instead of post variables. So for example: `name="firstname[]">` instead of `name="firstname">`.

Comment: you mean you want to add another form when clicking the button?

Comment: Refer to this:    http://jsfiddle.net/vbc6J/3/ This is in javascript. Need smth like this using for loop. Duplicating a form on button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to add more forms when the "Add a new form" button is clicked? We can achieve this using Javascript. But i'll be teaching you how to do it using a Javascript library called [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

First, download the library [here](https://jquery.com/download).

Then, we can proceed in creating the script.

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <!-- CHANGE THE NECESSARY FILE DEPENDING ON THE VERSION YOU HAVE DOWNLOADED -->
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){ /* PREPARE THE SCRIPT */       
    $("#add").click(function(e){ /* WHEN ADD BUTTON IS CLICKED */
      e.preventDefault(); 
      $(".jumbotron").append('First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname[]"><br>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname[]"><br>'); /* APPEND TWO MORE FIELDS */
    });

  });
</script>
```

You can check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rk6eyym6/2/) for an example.

Note, you have to add `[]` on the `name` tags of your input fields so that they'll be interpreted as an array when they are passed on. Not doing so will only cause to read the first set of data.

Comment: What if I want to store the values of different form into the database?

Comment: that is your server side script after you submit the form. #LoganWayne fixed your first problem.

Comment: You can use an INSERT query. You can check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for more information about it.

Comment: I am using the onchange=this.form.submit() function so that once i insert a name it will automatically insert into my database. However i need to make sure I insert and do an update when user changes the value, how do I go about with that

Comment: @DivyaK - you can post a new question about your problem. My answer only did solve the one you are asking for this post.